# Android - how to display large text

Tags: android

I have a txt file which is around 2MB. I need to display it in android. I have tried out WebView and it takes around 5 seconds to load and display the file. Is there any way I can get it rendered faster? Moreover, I dont want to load all the text at the start. Something like a scrollbar which displays elements efficiently is what I require. I need not stick to WebView alone, but can choose to show it using any efficient way.

Answer (score 1):

You can divide your text by paragraphs and use listview. show each paragraph of text in one item.